# The set of adherence values of a sequence $(x_n)$ is equal to $\bigcap_{n=1} cl\{x_n,x_{n+1},...\}$

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Ley $(X,\tau)$ topological space.

Proposition: The set of adherence values of a sequence $(x_n)$ is equal to $\bigcap_{n=1} cl\{x_n,x_{n+1},...\}$.

I know that $a \in X$ is an adherence value of $(x_n)$ in $X$ if: $\forall U$ neighborhood of $A$, $\forall n, \exists m \geq n$ st. $x_m \in U$, or in other words there is a subsequence converging to $a$.

And the left side of the equation is an intersection of the closures $cl\{x_1\}, cl\{x_1,x_2\},...$

$y \in cl(A) \iff \forall U$ neighborhood of $y, A \cap U \neq \emptyset $

So here's my "attempt":
$(\subseteq)$
Suppose $a$ is an adherence value of $(x_n)$. Then $a$ is a limit of some subsequence of $(x_n)$. But then $a \in cl\{ $elements of the subsequence $(x_{n_k}) \} $, which is in that intersection.

I want to know if what I wrote makes any sense and also want some hint for proving $(\supseteq)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set of adherence points of a sequence $(x_n)$ is *not* equal (in general) to the set of subsequential limits of the sequence, this is true only in sequential topological spaces (like first-countable ones). Just use the definition you stated, which is correct and which can be reformulated as: $x$ is a adherence point of $(x_n)$ iff for every $U$, which is an open neighbourhood of $x$, $U$ contains infinitely many terms from the sequence, i.e. $\{n: x_n \in U \}$ is infinite.

So let $x$ be an adherence point. Define $T_m = \{x_n: n \ge m \}$, the $m$-th tail of the sequence. We want to show that $x \in \operatorname{cl}(T_m)$, for any $m$, so fix $m$, and to see that $x \in \operatorname{cl}(T_m)$, we pick any open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ and see it intersects $T_m$. But this is clear, as we have $n \ge m$ with $x_n \in U$ (so $x_n \in T_m \cap U$) by your definition of adherence point. So $x$ is in the closure of all tails, as required.

And if $x$ is in the closure of all tails, then the adherence point property is also clear: pick $U$ an open neighbourhood of $x$ and $n$ any index. Then $x \in \operatorname{cl}(T_n)$ which means that $U$ intersects $T_n$, so for some $m \ge n$ we have $x_m \in U$, as required.

If you think about it, it's quite a simple reformulation of the definition. And there is no need for subsequences (which need not exist for adherence points in general).

Comment: Thanks a lot! And do you know how to prove that if the topological space is first countable  then I will have set of adherence points equal to set of subsequential limits?